# What should I learn if I want to implement dart-lang on jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, dart

This is a very hard maybe impossible task for me, but I still be interested in.

I'm a java programmer, and I found the [dart-lang](http://dartlang.org) is interesting. What should I learn if I want to implement it on jvm? like ruby on jvm(jruby)?

Comment: Have you looked at the current Dart source?  Java byte code is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html), JVM bytecodes, how the JVM does OOP.

There aren't a lot of recent references to JVM/bytecode hacking, but there are older references:

Two I've used are:

- [Component Development for the Java™ Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201753065)
- [Inside the Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0079132480)

Looking at how other languages approach code generation is helpful, if overwhelming. The simpler the language is, in general, the easier it is to learn from it. For example, [loop](http://looplang.org/) is a newer, smaller JVM language--it's also a different paradigm, so may or may not be directly helpful.

Obviously normal lexing and parsing will be required to process the source files, but Dart apparently uses [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) for its [grammar](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/language/grammar/Dart.g). Depending on how similar the Dart VM is to the JVM you may be able to gain a lot of knowledge by digesting the Dart implementation itself.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [the jdart project](http://code.google.com/p/jdart/).  I'm not sure how current it is - I think it was just a quick experiment.

It was created right back at the start, when Dart was released to the world last October.  [Here is the link](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/group/misc/browse_frm/thread/a938fcc42e83fc5b/2bd66e67ca3a2877?lnk=gst&q=dart%20java%20jvm#2bd66e67ca3a2877) noting its release on the dartlang bulletin board, which also has some discussion about how it works.

Comment: +1, I especially like the "the spec should change to do what I think is right" part :D